# iPad only app rejected because it does not work on iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode7

Apple rejected my App designed for iPad only (with device set to iPad only and targeted device family to 2 only in Xcode) because of the following reason : 2.10 - iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

I'm a little puzzled here. Are there other parameters that should be set to specify that it is an iPad only app that should not even be tested on iPhone devices ?

J.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appeal to the review board if you are sure it's iPad only.

Comment: What you have set in General>Development Info>Devices? Ipad only? Can you attach screenshot of it?

Comment: I'd appeal the rejection. There seems to be alot of new reviewers reviewing apps. Faster review times but lots of weird rejections for alot of devs. Did you upload iPhone screenshots in iTunes Connect? If you did, remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reply them with the specification of your app & tell them that this app is ONLY for iPad & not for iPhone. Ask them to review it again & confirm that you have NOT used anything related to iPhone while submitting your app on App Store.

> Though there is a requirement for iPhone apps that they should be executable in iPad without any modification, but vice versa is not applicable.

If you have any other app under your account which is also iPad only & is live, then you can give reference of that app in your reply.

You can reply to their message on Resolution Centre with your justification & resubmit your app again for review after verifying that it does not have anything related to iPhone. Your app will be accepted after that. Try this I have faced similar kind of issues many times.

Comment: Did that. They apologized...and did proper tests...and found real problems...at least we are moving forward...thanks

Comment: @jbegood Cheers... They are also humans & are allowed to do mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in Target of App, iPad is set as Device under Deployment Info.

[image]