# How to Restrict the iOS app only for iPads on app store?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, app-store

I want to publish my app but it should only be avaliable for Ipad. Iphone users mustn't be able to download it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPad only app rejected because it does not work on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346436/ipad-only-app-rejected-because-it-does-not-work-on-iphone)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov It's like yes. It has an answer for future problems on submitting the. thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose your application name under `Targets`, then `General` tab.
Then in deployment info section, choose only iPad.

In the same area, you can restrict the device orientation as well.
[image]

Comment: Good! so if I use some "Targets", for example an OneSignal sdk, does it must has the same set?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's a Build Setting, namely Targeted Device Families. Switch it to iPad:

[image]

Comment: Question is: "How to..."

Comment: And the answer is, set the Build Setting I just pointed you to. Did you try it? Look in Build Settings and see for yourself.

Comment: Added a screen shot. I don't see what else I can do short of moving the mouse for you. :)

Comment: "Look in Build Settings" makes it good. ;)

Comment: I added an imperative.